# What is the difference between `--headless-rendering` and the `-s` CLI options?

Tags: ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In Ignition Gazebo Fortress the CLI --help says:

```
  --headless-rendering         Run rendering in headless mode      
  -s                           Run only the server (headless mode). This        
                               overrides -g, if it is also present.
```

What is the difference between `--headless-rendering` and the `-s` CLI options?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28801/what-is-the-difference-between-%60--headless-rendering%60-and-the-%60-s%60-cli-options?/) by [azazdeaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34541/azazdeaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2023-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `-s` would still require an X display server if you use rendering sensors (eg. camera). With `--headless-rendering`, it uses EGL instead. See https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/headless_rendering.html

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1